# How to get a list of all builtins?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Learning Lisp from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) I'm constantly coming across new builtin *form* s (please correct me if haven't used the right terminology). The latest one was `'character`.

So I was wondering is there a command to get a list of all the builtins in Common Lisp? So that I could just easily skim through them all in one place.

Maybe something akin to Python's `dir(__builtins__)`.

*Additional tip would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could collect a list of all of the external symbols in the `COMMON-LISP` package:

```
(let (lst)
  (do-external-symbols (s (find-package 'common-lisp) lst)
    (push s lst)))
```

There are a lot of them!  Check out [the symbol index of the hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/X_AllSym.htm).

A lot of these symbols you'll probably never use, and I'm not sure it's worthwhile to look at each of them.

I would recommend becoming somewhat familiar with [all of the special forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababa.htm#clspecialops):

```
block      let*                  return-from      
catch      load-time-value       setq             
eval-when  locally               symbol-macrolet  
flet       macrolet              tagbody          
function   multiple-value-call   the              
go         multiple-value-prog1  throw            
if         progn                 unwind-protect   
labels     progv                                  
let        quote
```

Now, `CHARACTER` in particular is a standard type.  The hyperspec has [a list of those](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/04_bc.htm#standardizedatomictypespecs) as well, but I don't think there's a standard way to find all of the types programmatically.

Comment: IIRC, there are 978 symbols defined in the `COMMON-LISP` package in the standard.